# How to load a custom jquery mobile locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile

I've been trying to add a jquery mobile module to my wordpress website - the collapsible content block module. It works great when I enqueue jquery mobile via CDN in functions, ie.

function get_jqm() {
wp_enqueue_script(
 'jqm_js',
 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js',
 array('jquery'),
 '1.2.0'
 );

..but that adds the entire library, and it breaks my links and navigations, and the wordpress admin bar. I've downloaded a custom version of jquery mobile that really only includes the collapsible content block module, but I'm wondering what is the best way to enqueue a local version of jquery mobile plus custom jquery mobile CSS files. I've tried a number of suggestions by googling it but cannot find anything that gets it to work. It only works via CDN.

Answer (score 0):

To register your script, use:

```
wp_register_script('jqm_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/your/local/jquery.js', array(), null, false);
```

Set the last parameter as true to put the script in the footer and false to put it in the header of your site. 'get_template_directory_uri() returns something like

```
http://yourlocalsite:8888/wp-content/themes/your-theme/
```

and then from there you just need to provide the rest of the path to your js.

Then queue it up with:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jqm_js');
```

Similarly, you can do this with your CSS:

```
  wp_enqueue_style('app-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/your/app-css.css', false, '');
```

Comment: Great, is it best to do this via functions.php (I've read there's less conflicts this way), rather than header or footer, and how do you set the last parameter in functions?

Comment: Yes, the functions.php is the best place to do this. Here's the link to the docs for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script